# Button click event is working even if the validation is given

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function in javascript which will work with button click event. I need the function to work only if the total form validation return true. I am using jquery validation plugin to validate the form. Validation is working properly, but when I clicks the button, even though validation is there, still it is going inside the function.

I am calling the function like this:

```
document.getElementById('btnNext').addEventListener('click', handleFileSelect, false);

function handleFileSelect(evt) {
//My Code goes here
}

//This is my form..

<form id="someID">
<button id ="next" type="submit">
</form>

//And my validation will be as follows:

$("#posterForm").validate({
    rules: {
        //Here all the validation rules
    },
    messages: {
        //Here all the error messages
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing dom and jquery event listeners. The line `document.getElementById('btnNext').addEventListener('click', handleFileSelect, false);` is listening to dom events. You can just do

```
$('#btnNext').on('click', function(evt){
  //Validate the fields
  var valid;
  //set the valid field to true if the fields are true else set to false
  if (!valid)
    evt.preventDefault();
});
```

[preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) doc details this function.